# how to solve this kind of differential equation?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

If $x(t)$ is a solution of $(1-t^2)\,\text{d}x-tx\,\text{d}t=\,\text{d}t$

$x(0) = 1$ find $x(1/2)$ ??

my approach :

$$(1-t^2)\,\text{d}x - tx\,\text{d}t=\text{d}t$$
or, $$(1-t^2)\frac{dx}{dt} - tx=1$$
or, $$(1-t^2)\frac{dx}{dt} = 1+tx$$
or, $$\frac{dx}{dt} = \frac{1+tx}{1-t^2}$$

suppose $x=vt$
then $\frac{dx}{dt}=v+t\frac{dv}{dt}$

now 
\begin{align}
t\frac{dv}{dt} &=\frac{1+vt^2}{1-t^2} -v\\
&= \frac{1+vt^2-v+vt^2}{1-t^2}\\
&= \frac{1-v+2vt^2}{1-t^2}
\end{align}

what can I do now ?????

Comment: Please clear up your formatting; see the [MathJax guide](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference). Right now, it's hard to understand your question.

Comment: A better substitution might be $x=\frac{y}{\sqrt{1-t^2}}$ or $\frac{y}{\sqrt{t^2-1}}$. That will reveal there is a potential issue about $t=1$.

Comment: @almagest  still there is a problem

Comment: @SourasekharBanerjee Have you tried $x=\frac{y}{\sqrt{1-t^2}}$?

Comment: @almagest i have found the solution by using it.

Comment: @SourasekharBanerjee Excellent! Well done!

Answer (score 1):

Observe that
$$\frac{\mathrm d}{\mathrm dt}(x(t)\sqrt{1-t^2})=\frac{\mathrm dx}{\mathrm dt}\sqrt{1-t^2}-\frac{t}{\sqrt{1-t^2}}x(t)=\frac1{\sqrt{1-t^2}}\left((1-t^2)\frac{\mathrm dx}{\mathrm dt}-tx\right).$$
If $x$ is a solution of your ODE, this is equal to $\frac1{\sqrt{1-t^2}}$ and we can solve explicitly. This is a specific case of the [integrating factor](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Integrating_factor) method for first-order linear equations.

Answer (score 0):

The solution is obtained by changing t into sin(u), which can be guessed 
from the $1-t^2$ term in factor of dx.
It is easy to show that the new differential equation is an exact differential form $df$ of a function $f(u,x)$
Obtaining the function $f$ is obtained by solving two differential equations coming from the factors of du and dx